# Converting None to 0 (F#)

Tags: f#

This expression correctly evaluates to 225.58:

```
let alfki = ctx.``[dbo].[Customers]``.Individuals.ALFKI
let changeNoneToZero x = match x with | Some v -> v | None -> 0m
let freights = alfki.FK_Orders_Customers |> Seq.map (fun x -> changeNoneToZero x.Freight) |> Seq.sum
```

corresponding to the following database query:

```
select SUM(freight)
from dbo.Orders
where CustomerID = (
 select CustomerID from Customers
 where CustomerID = 'ALFKI')
```

Is there some built in equivalent or close analogue of the `changeNoneToZero` function?  Could I be seeking to `Seq.sumBy` something instead?

Comment: `Seq.choose id >> Seq.sum`?

Answer (score 4):

@ildjarn's approach of using `Seq.choose` works.  Instead of converting `None` to 0m and then summing everything, the following selects only those values that are not `None` and pipes them into `Seq.sum`:

```
let freights = alfki.FK_Orders_Customers 
    |> Seq.choose (fun x -> x.Freight) 
    |> Seq.sum
```

Thanks @ildjarn!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `Option.fold`:

```
alfki.FK_Orders_Customers |> Option.fold (fun _ a -> a) 0m
```

And you can make it generic:

```
let inline valOrZero ov = ov |> Option.fold (fun _ a -> a) LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
```

Comment: We would first need to select `Freight` from an order before piping into `Option.fold`, no?